# Showing three functions with Decoder 3-8

Tags: digital-logic, decoder

I`m trying to show 3 function with 3-8 decoder with only OR gates.
The following functions are:

1. F1 = A'BC' + AB'C' + ABC
2. F2 = A'B'C' + A'BC
3. F3 = ABC + AB'C' + A'BC' + A'BC

so what I did is:
[image: Circuit]

I need to know if I did it right or there is something wrong in my decoder.

Comment: You didn't show how you connected A, B and C to the inputs of the decoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connected them:

```
A -> i-0
B -> i-1
C -> i-2
```

It looks good to me.

Note that:

```
F3 = F1 + A'BC
```

So F3's OR gate only needs to be 2-inputs, at the cost of latency.